# Jenkins console does not show the output of command runs on docker container

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins, docker-container

Running below command to execute my tests on docker container

```
sudo docker exec -i 6d49272f772c bash -c "mvn clean install test"
```

Above command running on Jenkins execute bash. But Jenkins console does not show the logs for test execution.

Comment: sudo docker exec -i 34c9f13546ff bash -c "whoami; export DISPLAY=:99; Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1920x1920x24 > /dev/null 2>&1; mvn clean > /dev/null 2>&1;

Can anybody help me to correct the above command. I am really stuck with it.
I am running this command in Jenkins Execute Shell

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem with docker start (which is similar to docker exec).  I used the **-i** option and it would work fine outside Jenkins, but the console in Jenkins didn't show any output from this command.  I replaced **-i** with **-a** similar to the following:

```
sudo docker container create -it --name container-name some-docker-image some-command
sudo docker container start -a container-name 
sudo docker container rm -f container-name
```

The docker exec method doesn't have a **-a** option so possibly removing the **-i** option would work too (since you are not interacting with the container in Jenkins), so if that doesn't work than you can convert to the following commands and achieve similar results with standard out being captured.